# ldap server is unavailable

Tags: c#, ldap

I'm totally new to this

I've tried to connect to an ldap server using the following code.

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "abcdef", "OU=abcdef,DC=avengers,DC=net");
```

I'm getting an "LDAP server is unavailable" exception.

I've looked up other posts which recommended adding username and password to it but I wanted to use this specific overloaded method which takes in Context.Domain, Domain and Container parameters only.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When I was doing something similar I also had problems with using a `PrincipalContext` object. By using a variable instead I was able to access AD properties. E.G: `var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "pc-name", "DC=domain,DC=com", "user", "password"); ;
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using Active Directory.

**PrincipalContext** works well with **AD only**.
If your directory is OpenLDAP/ any other, then try below code

```
 public static void Main(String[] rags)
    {
        //If you are not sure about username and password, leave below 2 variables as it is
        String username="";        //Change to your username, if you have any
        String passwd="";           //Change to your Password, if you have any

        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://abcedf/OU=abcdef,DC=avengers,DC=net", username, passwd, AuthenticationTypes.None);           
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry,"ObjectClass=*");

        // Below statement will list all entries immediately below your BaseDN
        foreach (DirectoryEntry c in entry.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", c.Path);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.

I was passing in wrong value for the "Domain Name" parameter (second parameter). I was sending OU value instead of Domain Name.